# How to remove files Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.2

I am getting the below error after deleting file from the project,

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

I have tried  below ways to fix the above issue, but northing is worked for me.

1. Deleted the derive data, cleaned(cmd + shift + k) and built once
   again still I am getting the same error.
2. I have checked in build phase -> compile sources, no files are in red color to delete.
3. If remove the reference from the project, build is happening but files are still exit in our
   project folder. I want to delete those files permanently.

Please help to fix above issue.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the error Log.

Comment: Close `Xcode` open again and Wait for `Xcode` to indexing files.  check the duplicate file name.

Comment: I have checked it, no duplicate files present in the project.

Comment: If you look above the error, Xcode will tell you which ViewController is added/declared twice, navigate to it and remove the reference. Build and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you change any file folder location or change any Objective-C Bridging file path. Then it's happened some time.

1. Update your Bridging path.
2. Clean your project alt + Shift + Command + K
3. Quit Xcode completely Command + Q
4. Open project again and wait for Xcode to index files.[image: Check for bridging headers path as well]